# exporting the model parameters after training and testing

Tags: machine-learning, orange

I want to construct a python micro service to generate predictions based on inputs from web via an API.
I have trained a logistic regression model, but need to create a python script to run in AWS lambda or a container with minimum set of libraries.
How do I see and possibly export the model parameters?

Comment: Logistic regression only has one parameter, a vector. Save it as an array somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for - but you should check out the package 'pickle'. You can use it to easily dump your model into a file and load it again.